# How to create system wide variables?

Tags: c#, variables, system, global

I need to create a set of variables that can be accessed by any process on the entire computer. The requirement is communication between processes. This can also be just a single string that needs to be deserialized.

This seems like a fairly simple question. I already looked into `Mutex` and `Semaphore`, but these classes seem to be for thread synchronization, if I'm not mistaken.

**Is there a built-int functionality to do this, other than creating files or registry entries?**

Comment: I frequently use memory cache products to solve this kind of requirements. Memcached (an old solution) or hazelcast like product would solve your problem. Other than this you can create pipes with .Net, but it is error prone when it comes to concurrency.

Comment: I would want to avoid 3rd party libraries for this.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to use pipes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do pipes create sockets that could potentially be blocked by firewalls? Why are they error prone?

Comment: No, pipes do not create sockets, it is not a TCP connection. You just set a part in memory as shared among processes. It is error prone, because you will have to implement concurrency lock mechanisms yourself

Comment: Ok, I will look into that. I've also seen that EnvironmentVariables could be a potential solution. Do you think this would be a good solution to this?

Comment: more options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @bytecode77, actually I did not use EnvironmentVariabes to store data. I don't have a clear idea about pros-cons.

Comment: You can try using a [Memory Mapped File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A `mutex`can be used to across multiple processes.

You create it with

```
 new Mutex(true, "theMutex");
```

and can access it from other processes by using

```
new Mutex(false, "theMutex");
```

You the String int the constructor is a system wide identifier for the Mutex. You must only set the first parameter true in the one process that creates it.

(At least thats what i learned in my lecture today)

Comment: I've looked into mutexes and it seems to me like they are only for thread synchronization, not for passing data. Or is there a way an actual string can be passed to another process?

Comment: yeah, my bad. I found this at MSDN: [Interprocess Communications] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)